# gpg problem in using pass password manager

Tags: gpg, password-store

I would like to use the "pass" password manager.  I don't seem to be able
to get pass to recognize my public key.

```
$ gpg2 --list-keys

/home/johndoe/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
-------------------------------

pub   rsa4096/3AD31D0B 2011-02-08 [SCE]
uid         [ unknown] Fedora-SPARC (15) <fedora@fedoraproject.org>
sub   elg4096/A9DAE699 2011-02-08 [E]
```

... lots of other keys like the one above and then ...

```
pub   rsa2048/27FA9292 2016-03-31 [SC]
uid         [ultimate] John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>
sub   rsa2048/7C8FD1D9 2016-03-31 [E]

$ pass git init 27FA9292
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/johndoe/.password-store/.git/

pass insert pubs/checkbook
Enter password for pubs/checkbook: 
Retype password for pubs/checkbook: 
gpg: captain Password Storage Key: skipped: No public key
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key
fatal: pathspec '/home/johndoe/.password-store/pubs/checkbook.gpg' did not match any files
```

captain is the hostname.  Why can pass not find my public key?

Thank you.

Comment: This answers the question but I cannot figure out to mark it as such!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compress the two commands into one. You need to first initialise the pass store with your key and then, *separately*, initialise the git repository. Because, as the manual states, `pass git` only takes `git-command-args`.

So, the correct approach requires two steps:

```
pass init YOUR_KEY
pass git init
```