# How do I tell pass my GPG passphrase?

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I'm trying to set up [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org) and hitting a bit of a wall. I generated a new gpg key with `gpg --gen-key` and then ran `pass init 1E3C5C98` where `1E3C5C98` is the ID for my new key, at least as I understand it. It acts like it worked:

```
mkdir: created directory '/home/amanda/.password-store/'
Password store initialized for 1E3C5C98
```

And I can add new passwords with `pass insert Example/username` but when I try to view them I get `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key` --  I can't figure out how to tell `pass` what my gpg passhprase is, and pass isn't asking me for it. I read through [the pass docs](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/about/#EXTENDED%20GIT%20EXAMPLE) but I'm finding an answer there. I suspect I'm missing something super obvious.

The `pass` developers recommend `gpg-agent` but I'm also not totally sure how to tell `gpg-agent` to unlock my gpg key.

Per the comments, I tried running `pass Example/username` through `strace` -- I can add a password just fine with `pass insert Example/username` but when I try to view the password I see the "no secret key" error.

```
amanda@mona:~$ strace -e execve -F pass Example/username
execve("/usr/bin/pass", ["pass", "Example/username"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
execve("/usr/local/sbin/bash", ["bash", "/usr/bin/pass", "Example/username"], [/* 66 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/bin/bash", ["bash", "/usr/bin/pass", "Example/username"], [/* 66 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/sbin/bash", ["bash", "/usr/bin/pass", "Example/username"], [/* 66 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "/usr/bin/pass", "Example/username"], [/* 66 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/sbin/bash", ["bash", "/usr/bin/pass", "Example/username"], [/* 66 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "/usr/bin/pass", "Example/username"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
strace: Process 1388 attached
strace: Process 1389 attached
[pid  1389] execve("/usr/bin/tty", ["tty"], [/* 65 vars */]) = 0
[pid  1389] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid  1388] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1389, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid  1388] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1388, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
strace: Process 1390 attached
[pid  1390] execve("/usr/bin/which", ["which", "gpg2"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
[pid  1390] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1390, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
strace: Process 1391 attached
[pid  1391] execve("/usr/bin/getopt", ["getopt", "-o", "c", "-l", "clip", "-n", "pass", "--", "Example/username"], [/* 68 vars */]) = 0
[pid  1391] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1391, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
strace: Process 1394 attached
[pid  1394] execve("/usr/bin/gpg2", ["gpg2", "-d", "--quiet", "--yes", "--compress-algo=none", "--no-encrypt-to", "--batch", "--use-agent", "/home/amanda/.password-store/Exa"...], [/* 68 vars */]) = 0
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
[pid  1394] +++ exited with 2 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1394, si_uid=1000, si_status=2, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 2 +++
```

Note: I think this might be related: [gpg problem in using pass password manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273539/gpg-problem-in-using-pass-password-manager?rq=1) / [pass and gpg: No public key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226944/pass-and-gpg-no-public-key?rq=1)

Comment: you need to re-importing the private key firstly, `gpg --import myprivatekey.asc` then editing `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and add `pinentry-mode loopback`

Comment: Umm... I don't have a solution. But I might suggest `strace -e execve -F pass insert Example/username` to work out precisely how `gpg` is being called.

Comment: @AttRigh added that output.

Comment: Found the answer on another question. Voting to close this as a duplicate.